# sas do until and do while distance reaches 250 miles

Tags: sas

In the following program, complete the statement so that the program stops generating observations when Distance reaches 250 miles or when 10 gallons of fuel have been used.

```
Data work.go259;
    set perm.cars;
    do gallons = 1 to 10 .....;
    Distance= gallons*mpg;
    output;
    end;
run;
```

The correct answer is "do gallons = 1 to 10 while (distance <250)"
but I am wondering why "do gallons=1 to 10 until (distance =250) is incorrect? I assumed the do loop will stop when distance=250, therefore the program will stop generating observations when distance reaches 250.

Comment: What happened when you tested it? How are the results different?

Comment: This sounds like something out of a textbook so maybe they just wrote down the most common way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as understood, you wish to break a loop conditionally. Two easy ways are leave and goto (talk about blast from past.^^)  Here are two examples that do just that. There is command Continue as well, but haven't tested that out yet.

```
Data test_goto;
    do gallons = 1 to 10;
    Distance= gallons*75;
    output;
        if distance >=250 then goto hop_Out;
    end;
    hop_Out:
run;

Data test_leave;
    do gallons = 1 to 10;
    Distance= gallons*75;
    output;
        if distance >=250 then leave;
    end;
run;
```